# MySQL: Displaying the last child of the top 5 parent rows (no repeated parents)

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

i'm trying to get the last 5 messages that have a reply, by user. A user cannot be repeated in the query's result:

```
SELECT
message.id_message AS id_message, message.message AS message,
user.id_user AS id_user, user.name AS name, user.lastname AS lastname
FROM user
    JOIN message ON message.id_user = user.id_user
    JOIN reply ON reply.id_message = message.id_message
WHERE
    user.flg_ban IS NULL
    AND
    message.id_message IN (SELECT MAX(id_message) FROM message GROUP BY id_user)
    AND
    reply.id_reply IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY user.id_user
ORDER BY message.id_message DESC LIMIT 5
```

The result should be:

- 6. Skyler: This is the only message for Skyler
- 5. Jesse: Third message for Jesse
- 2. Walter: Second message for Walter

For some reason I'm only getting one record.

Fiddle of the structure: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f114b/1

Comment: you sqlfiddle is wrong  .. you have use starting form 6 but user_id  related to 1, 2 ,   ...  so is unsefull

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9452a/2   is just a sample  .. i have not evaluated  the corresponding name and id .and  for distinct result use distinct clause not group by

Comment: @scaisEdge sorry for that, link has been updated

Comment: Inthe actual  sqlfiddle there is 3 records .. as in your question  .. explain better and as in my sql fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . .

```
SELECT m.id_message, m.message, u.id_user, u.name, u.lastname, u.facebook_id AS facebook_id
FROM user u JOIN
     message m
     ON m.id_user = u.id_user
WHERE u.flg_ban IS NULL AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM reply r WHERE r.id_message = m.id_message) AND
      m.id_message >= COALESCE((SELECT m2.id_message
                                FROM message m2
                                WHERE m2.id_user = m.id_user AND
                                      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM reply r2 WHERE r2.id_message = m2.id_message)
                                ORDER BY m2.id_message DESC
                                LIMIT 4, 1
                               ), 0
                              );
```

Note that table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

I think this is a pretty direct translation of what you want.  The only slight quirk is the use of `LIMIT 4, 1` to get the fifth largest `id_message`.  MySQL doesn't support `IN` with correlated subqueries, so this is a convenient work-around.